# Batch testing showing false negatives in LUIS UI

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have been working on improving my bot accuracy and utilize the batch testing panel. I have about 1000 tests I run across 9 different intents. 1 week ago everything was working just fine, I had got them all working and I was seeing 100% passing across the board.

When I got to work on Monday I ran the batch testing panel (without any changes) and I was seeing all sorts of failures. It was showing that 6/9 batches failed with some having massive failures of maybe 100/300 passing.

At first I freaked because I as going to take this to prod and I couldn't figure out what happened.

However, when I clicked on "see results" the next scene showed that indeed all tests were still passing. It's just the first panel that is showing the wrong information about what is passing/failing.

Seems like there is some sort of bug here, I checked it out on another Model I had and it was having the same issue of the false failure reporting.

Comment: Can you hard refresh the website and try again?

Comment: Is the issue recurring or has happened only once?

Comment: @DFBerry I've tried restarting and using other browsers such as IE, it repros every time.

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid This is recurring, it is happening in both of my models. I can remove the batch test, re upload it as a new batch with a new name, it still fails with the same # of failures (although no failures when I click through to the results)

Comment: Please go into the LUIS portal and log an issue via "Support | General inquiry through user voice"

Comment: @dfberry thanks, I did. Is there any way to follow or see the progress on the bug after it's been submitted?

Comment: @DFBerry I think I found the cause. In my batch tests I am not worrying about Entity mapping, it was not something we're focusing on at this point as we are not utilizing the entity extraction yet. 

As of 8/17, when you didn't include any entity mapping in the test and it mapped an entity, that wouldn't be reported as a failure. But after 8/20 any test that mapped an entity that it wasn't explicitly told to expect counted as a failure. (despite the intent mapping correctly)

Comment: Setting up tests properly for entity mapping is a huge pain. Not only do you need to know all the entities the utterance could have but you need to know the exact start character and end character in the string for each entity. We have 345 tests failing because we don't define their entities. There is no way we're going to go through all those tests and meticulously update their entity mapping.

Comment: @DFBerry I'd like to update the "bug" I entered with the additional info I found but Not really sure how.